# Read from two files and print line1 from file 1 + all lines from file2 and do that for all lines in file 1

Tags: perl, text-processing

I have two tab delimited text files, one with city names the other with descriptions.  I'm trying to read line 1 from file one and combine it with lines 1-1000 in file 2 and print the combined lines one at a time.  I'd like to do this for each line of file 1.

Example File 1:

```
San Francisco
San Diego
San Mateo
```

Example File 2:

```
groovy
windy
hot
```

Desired output:

```
San Francisco groovy
San Francisco windy
San Francisco hot
San Diego groovy
San Diego windy
San Diego hot
San Mateo groovy
San Mateo windy
San Mateo hot
```

I've written something that can step through one file and read it and I have written multiple scripts with hard coded descriptions and have a .bat/.command file that I can run to run like 30 scripts to cover my parameters but I'm thinking there has got to be an easier way.
I'm opening files and chomping right now with a while loop but maybe this is not the best way to get the results I'm trying to get.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I have is this:

```
open (my $fh2, "cities.txt")
or die "Could not open file";
mkdir 'Output', 0755;

while (my $row = <$fh2>){ 
    print $row;
if ($row ne "end\n"){

chomp $row;
print "$row\n";

else {
    close $fh2;
        die;
}

}
```

I'm using set variables called v1 and combining using : $v1.$row to print both variables but I need 1 script per variable.

Tab delimited text is always what I've been told to use as a data source but it can rally be an delimited text file.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include what you've tried so far? Also, where does the tab-delimited part come into play? I only see one value per line...

Comment: Thanks for adding your existing code. I'm still confused about your explanation of tab-delimited, though: delimited implies a delimiter. For example, you've got `line\nline\nline`. When someone says _delimited_, I would expect to see `field\tfield\tfield\n` or `field,field,field\n`.

Comment: One more thing... in your question, you said lines 1-1000 of the second file. Did you mean all lines, or did you really mean lines 1-1000? (There's a small difference in the logic, i.e., stopping after line 1000.)

Comment: Re tab delimited I'm wrong you are right.  I'm just line\nline\nline.

Comment: I meant all lines not just 1-1000. Thanks.

Comment: This is sounding a bit like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what is this auxiliary script you're calling?

Answer (score 1):

You say that your files are tab-delimited, but I don't see any tabs in your sample input, so I'm going to go with that for now.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $fh, '<', 'cities.tsv') or die $!;
chomp(my @cities = <$fh>);
close($fh);

open($fh, '<', 'adjectives.tsv') or die $!;

for my $city (@cities) {
    seek($fh, 0, 0);

    while (my $adjective = <$fh>) {
        chomp($adjective);
        print "$city $adjective\n";
    }   
}

close($fh);
```

Comment: Thanks very much Matt.  I've edited my post with the details that you asked for and will try to use what you've provided.

Comment: @tlialin No problem. If you believe it's a good solution to your problem, you should [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I'm assuming the seek/re-read approach is to save reading the file into memory? I'm not sure that isn't a premature optimisation given that order of magnitude - 1000 lines of a few bytes isn't much of a memory footprint.

Comment: @Sobrique In this case, sure. But you know how these things go. In this example, it's 1000 lines, but in real life, it's 100,000,000 lines and now we're OOM.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick way to do this in R:

```
> file1 <- readLines("file1.txt")
> file2 <- readLines("file2.txt")
> writeLines(sort(as.character(outer(file1, file2, paste))))
San Diego groovy
San Diego hot
San Diego windy
San Francisco groovy
San Francisco hot
San Francisco windy
San Mateo groovy
San Mateo hot
San Mateo windy
```

If you want to write these to a file, use the `con` argument in `writeLines()`.

Comment: This question is tagged as `perl` but your answer isn't. It's probably worth  clarifying why you've suggested this approach.

Comment: Apologies, you are right. I thought this could include R.

Comment: It could - I don't necessarily think 'use a different tool' is an incorrect answer. It's just it helps if it also includes a reason why a screwdriver is better than a hammer in this scenario.